# Newton-Kantorovich theorem insufficient when the Jacobian is singular at solution

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, singularity, newton-raphson

I'm trying to improve my understanding of why the Newton-Kantorovich theorem is, in some ways, insufficient in the singular case.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $Df$ denote its (Frechet) derivative. Suppose $f(x^*)=0$. Since the hypotheses of the Newton-Kantorovich theorem don't include any conditions on $Df(x^*)$, the theorem should be applicable even when $Df(x^*)$ is singular.

There seem to be challenges with this though. For instance, if $Df(x^*)$ is singular, we are not guaranteed a ball about $x^*$ in which $Df(x)$ is nonsingular. So we have to be more careful about how we pick our initial guess $x_0$. There is nothing in the theorem indicating what kind of regions contain valid initial guesses.

Evidently there are other strict conditions that hold if we try to apply the Newton-Kantorovich theorem to $f$ when $Df(x^*)$ is singular. In his 1980 thesis *Analysis and Modification of Newton's Method at Singularitites*, A.O. Griewank states the following (he seems to use $\nabla$ to denote the derivative):

> If the [Newton-Kantorovich] theorem applies at $x_0$ with respect to the Euclidean norm of vectors and spectral norm of matrices, it can be seen that singularity of $\nabla f'(x^*)$ requires with $s:=x_0-x^*$,
> \begin{align}
> f(x^*+\lambda s)=f(x_0)(\lambda/||s||)^2.
> \end{align}

It does seem to severely restrict choices of $x_0$, but I don't understand why this is a necessary condition when the Newton-Kantorovich theorem holds at $x_0$ and $Df(x^*)$ is singular. Any hints or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the knowledge of the Lipschitz constant of $f'$ (or bound on $f''$) over a large region is a rather strong condition, and the admissibility condition on $x_0$ is really restrictive. Together they force that $f'$ is non-singular in the region of interest. // We (Griewank group) explored this a little more for a PhD thesis project https://edoc.hu-berlin.de/bitstream/handle/18452/17697/alabdallah.pdf. Some more Newton-fractal like plots of typical examples and solution strategies can be found at https://www2.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~llehmann/topics/newton-linesearch/

Comment: Thank you for these links. The dissertation by Alabdallah looks very interesting.